Do lightbeams redshift one another upon passing?
If it's true that anti-parallel light beams affect eachother gravitationally does this imply that they mutually redshift in addition to bending their paths towards one another?  For example consider to anti-parallel LASER beams passing through each other.  It seems reasonable except where would the energy go lost from the light when it turns red?

Why would energy be lost? The two anti-parallel laser beams blue-shift each other (by an insanely tiny amount) as they approach, and red-shift each other (by the same amount) as they separate.

Please write this as an answer.  How are they able to do anything as they approach?  Isn't gravitational effect limited by the speed of light, the same speed the light is moving at?  Seems that the only affect possible would be when they meet!
